# Can an SQL Server Failover Cluster support a named instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering, failover, instance

If I currently have `someName\instanceName` on a standalone SQL Server and I want to migrate to a failover cluster, http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/moving-a-standalone-instance-to-a-cluster-while-keeping-the-name-and-ip/ hints that I can give the cluster the network name `someName` but that page doesn't deal with instance names.  On the other hand, Figure 8-10 on https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2224049&seqNum=2 shows an instance name (with the default value) suggesting that you can create named instances.  What isn't clear to me from that page is whether `sql-cluster` refers to `SQL-C\MSSQLSERVER` (generically `clusterName` refers to `hostName\instanceName`) or if those three fields are independent and `sql-cluster\MSSQLSERVER` is a valid way to address that named instance on the cluster?  (And, of course, if the "SQL Server instance name" was not the default but, say, `myInstance`, is `sql-cluster\myInstance` valid.)  I've found conflicting hints and no conclusive or authoritative answers on the web.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either a default instance or a named instance on a Failover Cluster. I have supported hundreds of clusters, most of them used named instances.

When connecting to it, use networkname\instancename. You can use other ways, but it makes most sense to use networkname since that moves to another node on failover.

Comment: Are you saying "it makes most sense" to use `networkname\instancename` and not `hostname\instancename` since the latter doesn't move on failover?

Comment: @ChrisNelson, yes use networkname\instancename. When I said "it makes most sense", I was referring to only the part before the backslash. If you use hostname\instancename or clustername\instancename, it's not going to work when they are not the server hosting the SQL instance. Use networkname\instancename since networkname follows where the SQL instance lives.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm dense or dubious but the information I've gotten on the web has been all over the place... After filling out that form on `host1` and `host2`, both part of `myCluster`, and specifying "SQL Server Instance Name" of `myInstance` on both hosts, any and all clients would use `myCluster\myInstance` to access the database and whichever host was the active one in the failover cluster would process the requests.  Right?

Comment: @ChrisNelson, But what is the network name set to? Cluster name is not the same thing as the network name.

Comment: I don't know.  You tell me.  How do I (can I?) configure the cluster so existing connection strings which use `someName\instanceName` still work?

Comment: @ChrisNelson During setup, you'll be asked for a network name, this is SQL Server network name (client access point) resource that will be created and used. This name needs to be unique within your domain, additionally you can have a single default instance and multiple named instances. It's up to you as an administrator to choose.